# Has the apache2-dbg package been dropped from Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: apache2, 22.04, gdb

Has the apache2-dbg package been dropped from Ubuntu 22.04?  If so, is there any replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Yes, there is no apache2-dbg package anymore,but you are still able to debug. This is probably what you are looking for: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages